# How can I store a variable before submiting a form?

Tags: php

I want to store a variable called cpf, before submiting the whole form to the database.

I need to store it before because depending on that variable, the options inside a select will change and the user needs to choose between those options before submitting.

I've been having trouble doing that because when I put any buttons inside a form, whether it submits the whole thing or it doesnt work.

The last way that I tried was this:

`<button type="button" name="button" value="button">Click</button>`

```
<?php

        if(isset($_POST["button"])){
            $cpf_teste= $_POST["cpf"];
            $query_curso = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT DISTINCT CURSO FROM teste WHERE CPF IN ('$cpf_teste') GROUP BY CURSO;");
        }

?>
```

How can I make it so the only thing the button does is store the variable so I can use it to send a query to the db and show the options of a select.

I hope I made myself clear

Comment: You could control the display of the dropdowns entirely in JavaScript. with an AJAX request to fetch the option lists from the server. You can trigger the request when that cpf field is updated in the form, or when a specific button is pressed, before any submission occurs at all. Since AJAX requests asynchronous it won't post your whole form, and you can code it to just send the cpf value and nothing else.

Comment: Your current code is open to SQL injections Use parameterized queries and prepared statements.

Comment: Yeah, I was avoiding using ajax but it seems that there is no other way. Thanks for the hep though

Comment: Yeah, before finishing the project I'm going to change it to prevent sql injections

Comment: Do that now, so that you don't have to rewrite and re-test lots of sql code just after you've got everything working - that would be a big waste of time. The sooner you get into good habits the better

Comment: Ok, I'll get to it now